# Tensorflow, Keras: Tensor normalization by axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Assume we have images Tensor `A` with shape `(None, 200, 200, 1)`. where `None` is the batch size, and `(200, 200, 1)` is the image size.

How to perform normalization (0 to 1) on each image (not using `for` iteration)?

That is:

```
A[0] = (A[0] - A[0].min()) / (A[0].max() - A[0].min())
A[1] = (A[1] - A[1].min()) / (A[1].max() - A[1].min())
...
A[n] = (A[n] - A[n].min()) / (A[n].max() - A[n].min())
```

if I just directly use `A = (A - A.min()) / (A.max() - A.min())`, it will normalize all the images by the global `max` and `min`.  I wish to normalize each image with their own `max` and `min`.

In other words, how to achieve a `max` or `min` operation, that results in a shape of: `(None, 1, 1, 1)`, where each `(1, 1, 1)` contains the max or min of each image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tf.reduce_max` and `tf.reduce_min`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.random_normal(shape=(-1, 200, 200, 1))
B = tf.reduce_max(A, axis=(1, 2, 3))
C = tf.reduce_min(A, axis=(1, 2, 3))

print(B.shape)
print(C.shape)
```

Output:

```
(?,)
(?,)
```

Also, the output in your case needs to be of the shape `(None, 1, 1, 1)`, not `(None, 1, 1)`, as you have included the last channel dimension.

```
B = tf.reshape(B, (-1, 1, 1, 1))
C = tf.reshape(C, (-1, 1, 1, 1))

print(B.shape)
print(C.shape)
```

The above code gives the following output:

```
(?, 1, 1, 1)
(?, 1, 1, 1)
```

Finally, why are you subtracting the `max` from each pixel, do you mean to subtract the `min` for [normalizing each image between 0-1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range)?

```
D = (A - C) / (B - C)
print(D.shape)
```

gives

```
(?, 200, 200, 1)
```

as expected.